# Isometric embeddings with prescribed second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I'm looking for some non-rigidity result for isometric embeddings in euclidean space (codimension 2).
For example, any isometric embedding of the round $S^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$ is unique up to rigid motion.
Is there an isometric embedding of $S^2$ into $\mathbb R^4$ such that for example both principal curvatures are strictly less than one? I would be grateful for some reference on that subject.

Comment: I haven't dealt with 2nd fundamental form in higher codimension, but a glance at definition suggests that the product of principal curvatures should still be equal to the Gaussian curvature.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the notion of the principal curvatures $\kappa_i\in\mathbb{R}$ depends on there being a single normal direction. Such a notion is not well-defined when the codimension is greater than $1$.

Comment: That was my first reaction too, but the  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form#Generalization_to_arbitrary_codimension) generalizes the concept, including principal curvature, to arbitrary codimension.

Comment: I didn't see their article but presumably their generalisation is not an element of $\mathbb{R}$.